# Processing a list to build an ip in a string format

Tags: c#, strings

The point of this code is to build an ip from a list of type `ushort`.

```
var ip = new StringBuilder();
List<ushort> ipList = new List<ushort>(4) {192, 168, 1, 1};

ipList.ToList().ForEach(x => ip.Append(x + "."));

return ip.Remove(ip.Length - 1, 1).ToString();
```

The code works and outputs an ip as expected, but the formatting I give it leaves to be desired, having to delete the last element of the string does not look like a reliable solution or at least, I don't feel like it is.

The code above would output, before returning, the following string:

"192.168.1.1."

And after removing the last character it will look like this:

"192.168.1.1"

Comment: You do know about [the IpAddress class, right](http://www.snmpsharpnet.com/?page_id=60)?

Comment: No I didn't, but I think the use I am going to give to the string does not need this class since I just have to check an IP has been given to my device through DHCP, I don't have to interact with the ip in any way

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a [`string.Join()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method which would exactly do what you want like so

```
string ip = string.Join(".", ipList);
```

btw,  you don't need to call `ToList()` on a `List<T>`.

Comment: I like this one because it is straightforward.

Also, the tolist is a typo from my original code, I tried to provide an example without any of my code exported here, the data is given to me in an array, that's why the ToList exists

Comment: Ok, I will correct my code then, thanks for pointing that out,

Answer (score 10):

The biggest problem here is that an [IPv4 address is really four unsigned 8 bit integers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4), but you're using [16 bit unsigned integers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cbf1574z.aspx) to represent them.

You should be using an array of [bytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693.aspx) instead of ushorts.

Obviously, you'll still want to leverage the other answers and `Join` them as well.

Comment: I am using 16 bit unsigned integers because it's the format used by the device to return data since it uses the modbus protocol.

Comment: Why does the input dictate *your* representation of the data? Don't let some other programmer's poor decision "force" you into one. Create an adapter that transforms them into a proper representation. Hell, I'd consider creating your own `IPv4` struct and put that call to Join in a ToString method.

Comment: I can't argue you about that, i will create one for this and future matters regarding this.

I make sometimes questions which can look stupid, but my work does not revolve around optimal code rather than "resilient" code and I don't want that to affect my coding practices, I've seen such things.......

Comment: For giggles, I implemented an IPv4 struct. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/112088/ipv4-struct-utilizing-explicit-layout

Comment: That is fantastic, thanks for the time you invested in making that struct!

Comment: You're welcome. It was an interesting problem. Just be careful, it has some big vs. little endianness problems. Much better to use `System.Net.IPAddress`.

Answer (score 4):

*For those who have to use an old .NET Framework (prior to 4.0).*
To eliminate removing of the last character, you could use the `String.Join` method:

```
return String.Join(".", ipList.ConvertAll(x => x.ToString("0")).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 4):

I had not read all answers/comments before beginning this, so the answer might be a bit out of scope if all of those were taken into account. However, I still think this extension method might be useful for someone else, so I'll leave it here.

```
    public static IPAddress ToIPv4Address(this IReadOnlyCollection<ushort> source)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
        }

        if (source.Count != 4)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("An IPv4 address must consist of four bytes", nameof(source));
        }

        var invalidBytes = source.Where(v => v > byte.MaxValue).ToList();
        if (invalidBytes.Count > 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(source)} contains items that are out of the valid range for a byte: {string.Join(", ", invalidBytes)}", nameof(source));
        }

        return new IPAddress(source.Select(s => (byte)s).ToArray());
    }
```

This allows us to just use the built in `ToString` capabilities of the `IPAddress`class.

```
Console.WriteLine(new List<ushort>(4) { 192, 168, 1, 1 }.ToIPv4Address());
```

Additionally, this obviously checks that all items of the `List<ushort>` are in a valid range for an IPv4 address and that the source list has exactly four items.

Comment: @Heslacher Thanks. I saved the invalid items into a list, so that I could add them to the exception message, but maybe re-evaluating the expression would not really matter in that case anyways, since the exception bubbling up is probably the slowest part anyways. Not really decided about that one. :)