# IPv4 struct: Round 2

Tags: c#, reinventing-the-wheel, ip-address

## Summary

[Original Question here.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/112088/ipv4-struct-utilizing-explicit-layout)
[Updated GitHub link here](https://github.com/ckuhn203/Katas/tree/debffcea6bb227b724346f4f59c68fcc98f109fe/Rubberduck.Katas.Network)

I've taken an interest in lower level data structures and I implemented an 'Ip4Address` to get familiar with Explicit structure layout. It turned out to be an exercise in properly implementing a struct in general, but I digress. The idea here is that each Octet of the IPv4 address is represented by a byte in a single 32 bit unsigned integer.

## Things I've addressed since last review:

- Better argument validation all around.
- The struct is now immutable.
- Extracted a method for validating Ip addresses passed as strings.
- The code no longer needlessly initializes the struct only to overwrite it's values.
- Implemented `IEquatable` & `IComparable`.

  - In addition, I implemented and overrode the other methods that are recommended when implementing those two interfaces. This includes `Object.Equals(Object)`, `GetHashCode()`, and the equality operators.
- Added missing test cases.
- Implemented a `ToByteArray()` method.
- Removed useless variables from test cases.
- Use a method group for `address.Split('.').Select(a => Byte.Parse(a)).ToArray()`

  - I'm still on the fence about this last one. I like the explicitness of the syntax I originally used, but I changed it anyway.

## Things I did not address:

- Using `Assert.Throws()` for validating exceptions in my tests.

  - I'm not switching to NUnit. I like MSTest.
- Expression bodied member for `ToString()` override.

  - I'm hanging onto my curly braces for now. Expression bodied members are still feeling really weird to me.
- Properties for the Octets.

  - It felt really weird to explicitly lay out the structure of the struct, then to hide it all behind properties. I'm open to hearing a solid argument for doing this though. I just wasn't convinced during my last review.
- Use `uint` instead of `UInt32`

  - I explicitly used `UInt32` to make it clear that `Address` is a 32 bit integer and that the Octets use the same memory space.

## Questions:

- Did I get the `GetHashCode()` implementation right? I'm never really sure I that I got it right.
- My `CompareTo()` implementation feels messy. It's better than my [original implementation of it](https://github.com/ckuhn203/Katas/blob/d9ae8671e4521ddc7837b2f9557bc110dd1a9be0/Rubberduck.Katas.Network/Rubberduck.Katas.Network/Ip4Address.cs#L117-L167), but still doesn't feel very good.
- Does this code suffer from any Big Endian vs Little Endian issues? It was mentioned in my last review, but I wasn't able to confirm/refute it.
- As always, I'm open to any & all feedback.

## Ip4Address.cs

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rubberduck.Katas.Network
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct Ip4Address : IEquatable<Ip4Address>, IComparable<Ip4Address>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Represents the Base Ten IPv4 address as a raw integer.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>Overlays the Octet fields, so changing this value changes the Octets & vice versa.</remarks>
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        // ReSharper disable once BuiltInTypeReferenceStyle
        public readonly UInt32 Address;

        // Each Octet is mapped to a byte of the address.
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public readonly byte Octet1;
        [FieldOffset(1)]
        public readonly byte Octet2;
        [FieldOffset(2)]
        public readonly byte Octet3;
        [FieldOffset(3)]
        public readonly byte Octet4;

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new Ip4Address from a byte array.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="address">
        /// Must be an array of Length 4. 
        /// Index 0 is mapped to the first octet.
        /// </param>
        public Ip4Address(byte[] address)
        {
            if (address == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(address));
            }

            const int expectedLength = 4;

            if (address.Length != expectedLength)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(address)} array must have a length of {expectedLength}.", nameof(address));
            }

            // Set address because we must set all fields in the struct, else there is a compiler error.
            // It seems the compiler isn't aware that they're really the same thing.
            // We could call `:this()`, but I don't want to initalize it before arg checking.
            Address = 0;

            Octet1 = address[0];
            Octet2 = address[1];
            Octet3 = address[2];
            Octet4 = address[3];
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new Ip4Address from it's base ten representation.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="address">Base ten representation of an IPv4 address. 
        /// UInt32.MaxValue results in an IP of "255.255.255.255".
        /// </param>
        public Ip4Address(UInt32 address)
            : this()
        {
            Address = address;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new Ip4Address from a well formed IP address. i.e. "10.10.1.255"
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="address"></param>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"></exception>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentException">If the <paramref name="address"/> is not a valid IPv4 address.</exception>
        public Ip4Address(string address)
            : this(ParseStringAddress(address))
        { }

        // Using a private method because this work must be done prior to passing it off to a chained ctor call.
        private static byte[] ParseStringAddress(string address)
        {
            if (address == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(address));
            }

            // Validation pattern shamelessly borrowed from http://www.regextester.com/22
            // It validates not only the format, but the number ranges too, 
            // so by time we're casting to a byte, it's a safe operation.
            var ipRegex = new Regex(@"^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$");

            if (!ipRegex.IsMatch(address))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"{address} is not a valid IPv4 address.", nameof(address));
            }

            return address.Split('.').Select(Byte.Parse).ToArray();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Indicates whether this instance and a specified object are equal.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// true if <paramref name="obj"/> and this instance are the same type and represent the same value; otherwise, false. 
        /// </returns>
        /// <param name="obj">The object to compare with the current instance. </param>
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (!(obj is Ip4Address))
            {
                return false;
            }

            return this.Equals((Ip4Address)obj);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Indicates whether the current object is equal to another object of the same type.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// true if the current object is equal to the <paramref name="other"/> parameter; otherwise, false.
        /// </returns>
        /// <param name="other">An object to compare with this object.</param>
        public bool Equals(Ip4Address other)
        {
            return Address.Equals(other.Address);
        }

        public static bool operator ==(Ip4Address ip1, Ip4Address ip2)
        {
            return ip1.Equals(ip2);
        }

        public static bool operator !=(Ip4Address ip1, Ip4Address ip2)
        {
            return !(ip1 == ip2);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Compares the current object with another object of the same type by doing a byte by byte comparison of the Octets.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// A value that indicates the relative order of the objects being compared. The return value has the following meanings: Value Meaning Less than zero This object is less than the <paramref name="other"/> parameter.Zero This object is equal to <paramref name="other"/>. Greater than zero This object is greater than <paramref name="other"/>. 
        /// </returns>
        /// <param name="other">An Ip4Address to compare with this object.</param>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Comparing the <seealso cref="Address"/> is not sufficient because it represents 4 bytes (Octets) of data, not a single integer.
        /// Therefore, this implementation does an Octet by Octet comparison.
        /// </remarks>
        public int CompareTo(Ip4Address other)
        {
            if (this.Equals(other))
            {
                return 0;
            }

            var octet1Comparison = Octet1.CompareTo(other.Octet1);

            if (octet1Comparison != 0)
            {
                return octet1Comparison;
            }

            var octet2Comparison = Octet2.CompareTo(other.Octet2);

            if (octet2Comparison != 0)
            {
                return octet2Comparison;
            }

            var octet3Comparison = Octet3.CompareTo(other.Octet3);

            if (octet3Comparison != 0)
            {
                return octet3Comparison;
            }

            // Should never return 0 at this point, because we checked very early if they were equal.
            return Octet4.CompareTo(other.Octet4);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the hash code for this instance.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// A 32-bit signed integer that is the hash code for this instance.
        /// </returns>
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Address.GetHashCode();
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{Octet1}.{Octet2}.{Octet3}.{Octet4}";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the Octets in the form of a byte array. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// A byte array of length 4, containing the Octets of the address.
        /// <see cref="Octet1"/> is mapped to index 0 of the array.
        /// </returns>
        public byte[] ToByteArray()
        {
            return new byte[] { Octet1, Octet2, Octet3, Octet4 };
        }
    }
}
```

## The Tests

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace Rubberduck.Katas.Network.Tests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class Ip4AddressTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void CanCreateFromString()
        {
            Ip4Address ip = new Ip4Address("192.10.1.1");

            Assert.AreEqual(192, ip.Octet1);
            Assert.AreEqual(10, ip.Octet2);
            Assert.AreEqual(1, ip.Octet3);
            Assert.AreEqual(1, ip.Octet4);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
        public void WhenStringHasSpaces_ThrowsArgException()
        {
            new Ip4Address("1 . 2 . 3 . 4");
        }

        [TestMethod]
        [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
        public void WhenStringIsMalformed_ThrowsArgException()
        {
            new Ip4Address("10.10.1..");
        }

        [TestMethod]
        [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
        public void WhenStringHasAlphaChars_ThrowsArgException()
        {
            new Ip4Address("10.10.A.1");
        }

        [TestMethod]
        [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
        public void WhenStringIsWellFormedButNotAValidIpAddress_ThrowsArgException()
        {
            new Ip4Address("123.456.789.999");
        }

        [TestMethod]
        [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentNullException))]
        public void WhenByteArrayArgIsNull_ThrowsNullArgException()
        {
            new Ip4Address((byte[])null);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentNullException))]
        public void WhenStringArgIsNull_ThrowsNullArgException()
        {
            new Ip4Address((string)null);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void CanCreateFromByteArrayAndGetEquivalentArrayBack()
        {
            var expected = new byte[] { 192, 10, 1, 1 };

            var ip = new Ip4Address(expected);

            CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, ip.ToByteArray());
        }

        [TestMethod]
        [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
        public void ByteArrayLengthCannotBeLessThan4()
        {
            new Ip4Address(new byte[] { 192, 10, 1 });
        }

        [TestMethod]
        [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
        public void ByteArrayLengthCannotBeGreaterThan4()
        {
            new Ip4Address(new byte[] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 });
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void CanCreateFromBaseTenAddress()
        {
            //i.e. can create from an integer.
            var ip = new Ip4Address(UInt32.MaxValue); //0xFFFFFFFF

            Assert.AreEqual(255, ip.Octet1);
            Assert.AreEqual(255, ip.Octet2);
            Assert.AreEqual(255, ip.Octet3);
            Assert.AreEqual(255, ip.Octet4);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void ToStringReturnsExpectedResult()
        {
            var ip = new Ip4Address(new byte[] { 10, 10, 1, 1 });

            Assert.AreEqual("10.10.1.1", ip.ToString());
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void WhenTwoIpAddressesAreTheSame_TheyAreEqual()
        {
            var ip1 = new Ip4Address("10.10.1.1");
            var ip2 = new Ip4Address("10.10.1.1");

            //Assert.AreEqual calls Object.Equals(Object), so test both IEquatable & Object.Equals override.
            Assert.IsTrue(ip1.Equals(ip2));
            Assert.AreEqual(ip1, ip2);
            Assert.IsTrue(ip1 == ip2);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void WhenTwoIpAddressesAreNotTheSame_TheyAreNotEqual()
        {
            var ip1 = new Ip4Address("10.10.1.1");
            var ip2 = new Ip4Address("192.10.1.1");

            //Assert.AreEqual calls Object.Equals(Object), so test both IEquatable & Object.Equals override.
            Assert.IsFalse(ip1.Equals(ip2));
            Assert.AreNotEqual(ip1, ip2);
            Assert.IsTrue(ip1 != ip2);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void CompareTo_GreaterThan()
        {
            var ip1 = new Ip4Address("10.10.0.1");
            var ip2 = new Ip4Address("10.9.1.2");

            Assert.AreEqual(1, ip1.CompareTo(ip2));
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void CompareTo_LessThan()
        {
            var ip1 = new Ip4Address("10.9.1.2");
            var ip2 = new Ip4Address("10.10.0.0");

            Assert.AreEqual(-1, ip1.CompareTo(ip2));
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void CompareTo_Equal()
        {
            var ip1 = new Ip4Address("10.10.1.1");
            var ip2 = new Ip4Address("10.10.1.1");

            Assert.AreEqual(0, ip1.CompareTo(ip2));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering your questions.

1. Your `GetHashCode()` implementation is good enough.
2. It's better to store octets in the reverse order.
   The highest bits of an address should be stored in the `Octet4`, the lowest - in the `Octet1`.
   Thus you will be able to simplify your `CompareTo` method:

   ```
   public int CompareTo(Ip4Address other)
   {
       return Address.CompareTo(other.Address);
   }
   ```
3. And yes, this code depends on the endianness. If you are planning to use it on Big Endian systems too, you could use the [`BitConverter.IsLittleEndian`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.islittleendian.aspx) static field to detect endianness and reverse octets if needed:

   ```
   var bytes = address.Split('.').Select(Byte.Parse);
   if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
   {
       bytes = bytes.Reverse();
   }
   return bytes.ToArray();
   ```

   In this case you should also add a remark to descriptions of the `Ip4Address(byte[] address)` constructor and to the `ToByteArray` method, that the byte order depends on the endianness.
4. Your `Equals(object obj)` method can be simplified to:

   ```
   return obj is Ip4Address && this.Equals((Ip4Address)obj);
   ```

---

My vision of the `ParseStringAddress` static method:

```
private static byte[] ParseStringAddress(string address)
{
    if (address == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(address));
    }

    string[] inputOctets = address.Split('.');

    const int expectedMaxLength = sizeof(uint);

    // Questionable.
    // Should we handle short forms of the IPv4, such as
    //   10.1.1
    //   192.168
    //   0
    // or not?
    // If not, rename the 'expectedMaxLength' back to the 'expectedLength'
    // and replace the '>' with the '!=' in the following condition:
    if (inputOctets.Length > expectedMaxLength)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(...);
    }

    byte[] outputOctets = new byte[expectedMaxLength];
    for (int i = 0; i < inputOctets.Length; i++)
    {
        int outputOctetIndex = BitConverter.IsLittleEndian ? expectedMaxLength - 1 - i : i;
        if (!Byte.TryParse(inputOctets[i], out outputOctets[outputOctetIndex]))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(...);
        }
    }

    return outputOctets;
}
```

In addition to the normal input strings it also accepts input strings:

- *Questionable.* With the short form of IPv4 address representing a subnet, such as `10.1.1` (equivalent of `10.1.1.0`).
- Containing space chars, such as `1 . 2 . 3 . 4`.

This method outputs octets in the right order depending on the `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` value.

Comment: I actually just found a really nasty bug. IP Addresses are in *Network* order (Big Endian). So, my `Address` field is returning exactly the wrong address... Thanks @Dmitry. I'm not sure I would have found it without your answer prompting me.

Comment: @RubberDuck Glad to be useful. I've also added my vision of the `ParseStringAddress` method. This doesn't mean that something is wrong with yours, it's just my IMO: I prefer to parse input as much as possible.

Comment: Interesting. I hadn't considered subnets, but I decided that addresses containing spaces were likely invalid after having it pointed out to me in the previous review. I corrected the Octet ordering, which fixed the bug & greatly simplified the `CompareTo` implementation as you suggested. I decided not to bother making it work on Big Endian architecture (for now at least), as it was just an exercise. Maybe I'll do that later. I really can't thank you enough. Great review.

Answer (score 1):

Consider adding a constructor `Ip4Address(byte, byte, byte, byte)` so that client code doesn't have to allocate a byte array or string, or manually convert the bytes to a `uint`.

---

`ParseStringAddress` accepts twice as many strings as there are IPv4 addresses. The reason is the behaviour of the `$` anchor:

> The match must occur at the end of the string or line, **or before `\n`** at the end of the string or line.

So `new Ip4Address("0.0.0.0\n")` will not throw an exception.

You can instead use the `\z` anchor:

> The match must occur at the end of the string only.

I wouldn't go so far as to call this a bug, but it's good to be aware of. I consider the current behaviour to be surprising just because no other whitespace is allowed.

Comment: That's what I get for not working the regex out myself I suppose. Good call on the extra ctor. +1